# Can't use Volume Keys but I can use brightness keys on Lubuntu 16.04

Tags: sound, keyboard, lubuntu, lxde

So, installed lubuntu 16.04 and everything was working great excep the volume keys. I've already tried many fixes, including:
http://wiki.lxde.org/en/LXDE:Questions#How_do_I_make_my_keyboard_volume_buttons_work.3F
reinstalling alsa and pulsesound to no avail. I still can't get the volume keys to work. I'm new to linux so please bear with me.

Really appreciate any help I can get. I've already spent so many hours trying to find a fix but nothing worked for me.

Some additional info: Laptop asus a4-1200 x102ba, volume keys are fn 10, 11 and 12.

Answer (score 2):

If 2 out of 4 work, you are 50% ahead of many users.:)

First, find out if your keys are recognized at all. Open a Terminal and run this program:

```
$ xev
```

Then hit some keys. If your keys are recognized at all, then when you press them, some complicated messages will appear. Try keys that work "a", for example, then your ones that don't work.  If the system shows the keys are alive, then you have the problem of connecting those keys to the sound controller.

If the keys don't have any effect, my experience tells me that you OS might be installed with the wrong keyboard layout.  The keys are not working because, well, the OS does not know they are there. You can fix that deep in the guts of the X11 configuration, but it seems to me that has become a lost art and the default Ubuntu install doesn't even create an X11 configuration file anymore.

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 with XFCE, in the menu under Settings -> Keyboard -> Layout, there is a place where you can go looking for layouts. Maybe you won't find one that looks more like what you have, but maybe you will.

I remember a program in the olden days that you  could use to choose a layout. It would show its picture of what it thinks the keyboard ought to look like. The screen keyboard would light up, to let you test how it saw the keys.  We needed that when as student came from Germany with a keyboard that had about 5 keys we had never seen before.  I can't find that program now, but maybe some other reader will know if Ubuntu has it.

This page has most of the same ideas I would guess, but it was written quite a while ago. I did not hear of keytouch before, but it still exists in the repository and maybe it will help

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MultimediaKeys

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Xev  was giving me incorrect answers on volume, keyboard as far as I could tell was right. About keytouch,  I tried but all I could get installed was the editor, which recognized the media keys but needed non editor to work. After all I decided to try another district and tested the live version of mint 17.3 xfce and everything worked out of the box, despite a small decrease of performance. So now I'm using it and all is solved. Thanks again!

Comment: Please click the up arrow to say this is solved.

Answer (score 2):

I installed `kmix` on Ubuntu 18.04 and that did the trick:

1. Install:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install kmix
   ```
2. Reboot
3. Open `kmix`.
4. <kbd>Settings</kbd> → <kbd>Configure shortcuts</kbd> and this will show up:
   [image: kmix shortcuts]
5. set the Default option for Decrease Volume, Increase Volume and Mute and press <kbd>OK</kbd>.

**Note:** *KMix will add a volume slider to your panel*

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]! **;-)** Great first answer!  An edit *and an upvote!* **0:-)** Could you please review my **[edits](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1157199/revisions)** and also review the [editing help](/editing-help) to improve the readability of your answers in the future... **;-)**  Also: your avatar doesn't show: Broken link (private instead of public pic on google docs?)  **:-(**

Answer (score 1):

I had a very similar problem on a Lenovo T440p on Lubuntu 16.04 (volume keys are fn-F1, F2, F3, F4 = mute, vol-, vol+, mute mic) .

What ultimately seemed to be the problem that ALSA configured the HDMI module rather than Intel PCH as the default sound card, and the mixer commands (through amixer) went to that - though strangely enough, it was like that to only some applications: `aplay -l` and amixer would see HDMI as the default, but firefox (through pulseaudio) as well as Audacious (configured to the ALSA default devices) would play fine.

Fixed it by adding to `/etc/asound.conf` (might not exist yet):

```
defaults.ctl.card 1
defaults.pcm.card 1
```

where 1 is the number of the standard soundcard, which might be different for you (try `aplay -l`).

You might also want to look at the keybindings in `~/.config/openbox/lubuntu-rc.xml` .